# Python: format negative number with parentheses

Tags: python

Is there a way to use either string interpolation or `string.format` to render negative numbers into text formatted using parentheses instead of "negative signs"?

I.e. `-3.14` should be `(3.14)`.

I had hoped to do this using string interpolation or `string.format` rather than needing an import specifically designed for currencies or accounting.

Edit to clarify: Please assume the variable to be formatted is either an `int` or a `float`.  I.e. while this can be done with regular expressions (see good answers below), I was thinking this would be a more native operation for Python's formatting functionality.

So to be clear:

```
import numpy as np
list_of_inputs = [-10, -10.5, -10 * np.sqrt(2), 10, 10.5, 10 * np.sqrt(2)]
for i in list_of_inputs:
    # your awesome solution goes here
```

should return:

```
(10)
(10.5)
(14.14)
10
10.5
14.14
```

Clearly there is some flexibility about that last one.  I had hoped the "put negative numbers in parentheses" would be a natural argument of string interpolation or `string.format` so that I could use other formatting language while setting the display style of negative numbers.

Comment: what is the rule for cutting sqrt(2) ? (that's not the value, btw)

Comment: Ideally, the solution would let the user spec the display format of decimals at the same time they spec the display style of negative numbers.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need to handle possibly-negative numeric input:

```
print '{0:.2f}'.format(num) if num>=0 else '({0:.2f})'.format(abs(num))
```

Comment: Almost DRY: `fmt = '{0:.2f}' if num >= 0 else '({0:.2f})'; print(fmt.format(abs(num)))`

Answer (score 4):

This is what subclassing the formatter class is for.  Try the following:

```
import string
class NegativeParenFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        try:
            if value<0:
                return "(" +  string.Formatter.format_field(self, -value, format_spec) + ")"
            else:
                return string.Formatter.format_field(self, value, format_spec)
        except:
            return string.Formatter.format_field(self, value, format_spec)

f = NegativeParenFormatter()
print f.format("{0} is positive, {1} is negative, {2} is a string", 3, -2, "-4")
```

this prints:

```
'3 is positive, (2) is negative, -4 is a string'
```

Comment: Is there any way to get it so that this is the `Formatter` that gets used when I call the `"somestring".format()` method? I assume there's no easy way, since the `"somestring"` is a `str` and will call the builtin `str.format`.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas has a display option for *floats* and numpy has a display option for any dtype:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1., -2], [-3., 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

*Note: A is a float column, B is an int column.*

We can just write a simple formatter depending on the sign of the number:

```
In [12]: formatter = lambda x: '(%s)' % str(x)[1:] if x < 0 else str(x)

In [13]: pd.options.display.float_format = formatter

In [14]: df  # doesn't work for the int column  :(
Out[14]:
      A  B
0   1.0  2
1 (3.0)  4

In [15]: df.astype(float)
Out[15]:
      A     B
0   1.0 (2.0)
1 (3.0)   4.0
```

You can also configure numpy's print options:

```
In [21]: df.values # float
Out[21]:
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]])

In [22]: df['B'].values # int
Out[22]: array([2,  4])

In [23]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': formatter, 'float': formatter})

In [24]: df.values # float
Out[24]:
array([[1.0, (2.0)],
       [(3.0), 4.0]])

In [25]: df['B'].values # int
Out[25]: array([(2), 4])
```

Note: this doesn't change the way the data is stored, just the way you view it.

Comment: Are you aware of any procedure which stores the negative numbers in a dataframe in parentheses instead of just displaying them?

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest approach would be to use a trinary.

```
num = -3.14
output = "({})".format(math.fabs(num)) if num < 0 else "{}".format(num)
```

I can't remember if this works with a straight print statement instead of an assignment.  I will check this when I get by an interpreter.

**Thanks LartS for 3.x confirmation:** I further confirmed against(3.x and 2.x)

```
print("({})".format(math.fabs(num)) if num < 0 else "{}".format(num))
```

Does work

Comment: `print("({})".format(math.fabs(num)) if num < 0 else "{}".format(num))
` works on python3

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this in a dataframe instead of a single variable?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this

```
float = -3.14
num=  "(%(key)s)" %{ 'key': str(abs(float))} if float < 0 else str(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionals in a Python print statement:

```
print "%s%d%s" % ( "(" if (i<0) else(""), i, ")" if (i<0) else("") )
```

Comment: `print(("(%d)" if i < 0 else "%d") % abs(i))` does `i < 0` only once.